# Magento API error

Tags: api, soap

One of my developers trying to access API of Magento engine in order to integrate the Magento site with a POS system . He is using SOAP version 2

**Error is as follows :** Kindly help

> SoapFault exception: [1] Internal Error. Please see log for details.
>   in
>   /home/letex/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Soap.php:196
>   Stack trace:#0
>
> /home/letex/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract.php(140):
>   Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Soap->fault('1', 'Internal Error....')#1
>
> /home/letex/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract.php(48):
>   Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract->_fault('internal')#2